# Are there call events FROM Skype?

Tags: skype

This is more about integration of Skype with one of our custom products. Is there a way (API etc.) to be notified of call events happening in Skype ? I'm not talking about triggers in our app that makes call through Skype, more like listeners that get call notifications from Skype that it is making a call.

BarryBithead

Answer (score 0):

If you've talking about tracking a call in the Lync 2013 / Skype for Business client, then you can use the [Lync Client SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=36824).  The SDK provides everything you asked for, track calls the client is currently involved in and also automate the client to make and control calls.  The Client SDK comes with some basic examples to get you going.

If you've talking about consumer skype client, I have no idea.